# Trying to add multiple imap accts to outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have been able to add 1 POP3 and 4 IMAP accounts to Outlook. When I try to add another IMAP account, it doesn't work even though I have reviewed that the settings and password are correct.

Is there a limit to the number of accounts that can be added using IMAP or a limit to the number of accounts that I can use in Outlook 2010?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "*it doesn't work*"?

Comment: Outlook fails to connect. It keeps bringing up a logon screen when attempting to "test connection" as if the user ID or password were incorrect. But I know both are correct and have been very careful to make sure that I am typing everything in correctly. I also went to gmail to make sure my user ID and password were correct. I reset the password, restarted laptop (Alienware MX15), Windows 7, MSOffice Pro Plus 2010.

Comment: In my personal opinion, it is more likely that the problem is specific to that single email account than to the total number of accounts you have.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will try adding a different IMAP acct. Currently I have setup one POP acct and 4 IMAP accts. Will post result of further testing.

Comment: I think you may be correct. And I am suspecting that the User ID may contain to many characters (17 characters) as I cannot add this account to my Apple Itouch either. Everything else other than the length of the User ID is the same as my other accts. And I can login to the acct by going to gmail.com Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

While I would doubt that the number of email accounts in Outlook is limited (especially to such a low number), I can't rule it out.
Nevertheless, I would advise you look into compatibility issues between Outlook 2010 and you email provider.

If I understood your comment correctly, you're trying to set up Gmail in Outlook 2010. A quick look into the [Supported IMAP client list](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75726&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1x30fs99wnaap&cbrank=3) shows that Outlook 2010 is not listed. I don't know if that means 2010 is just unsupported or if it simply doesn't work at all.

Please note, the [setup instructions for Outlook 2007](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77689) specifically note that you should enable IMAP support in Gmail. Forgetting to do so might result in the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: Wish it was as simple as that but I already have 4 gamil accounts setup as IMAP on Outlook 2010. I am having the same problem just trying to add the particular acct on my Apple Itouch which also contains other gmail IMAP accts.

Comment: Since it is now working on both my laptop and Itouch and the error I was getting was a failure to authenticate I can only draw the conclusion of: I was able to connect from IE but not Outlook or my Apple Itouch with autentication faliures. I would guess that gmail servers did not update my password change across all servers because everything just worked the next morning.

Answer (score 0):

If all of these different IMAP accounts are hosted on the same server, then you may be only allowed to have so many IMAP connections at once, controlled on the server-side.  Outlook uses more than one connection to keep each IMAP account up-to-date when active.

So it'd be up to your email provider to check/confirm/fix this.

From Google [Gmail help](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97150):

> **Too many simultaneous connections**  
>  According to the Gmail Terms of Use, each user account is intended for single use. This means
>   that if you have multiple users frequently accessing the same account
>   or more than one IMAP1 client accessing Gmail at the same time, you
>   may reach a connection threshold and receive the error message, 'Too
>   many simultaneous connections.' 
>   Gmail currently has a limit of
>   10 simultaneous IMAP connections per account. 
>   Please note that
>   your mail client may actually open multiple connections in the
>   background. This means it's possible to reach a connection threshold
>   simply by using only two mail clients to access the same account at
>   the same time. 
>  If you often use multiple mail clients or mobile
>   devices with the same Gmail account, we recommend closing and/or
>   signing out of any mail clients you're not actively using.

Comment: Well, today it has decided to work!!! :) Deleted one of the IMAP accts then tried adding it back and adding the problem acct and IT WORKED!!! Don't know why, did everything the same but now it worked. I won't question it, I will just take the win this morning and hope the rest of my day goes as well. Thank all of you for your assistance...doug...